# Local Gorenstein ring and unique factorization domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is every local Gorenstein, integrally closed, integral domain, going to be an unique factorization domain?

Comment: No. As a simple example, take $k[[x,y.z]]/(z^n-xy)$.

Comment: @Mohan Are there similar counter-examples if we additionally assume that the local ring corresponds to the localization at an isolated singularity of dimension at least $3$?

Comment: Take $k[[x,y,z,w]]/(xy-zw)$. For larger dimension these exist, but not as easy as these by Grothendieck-Lefschetz.